# Pintar una fila que contenga una palabra

Tags: html, jquery, html5, datatables, jquery-ui

Tengo una tabla que genero con *HTML* y desde *JQuery* quiero que si hay un registro con un string en concreto, por ejemplo "Ferrari" lo ponga en color rojo.

La tabla que tengo seria como esta:

```
<table id="tabla-marcas">
    <thead>
        <tr><th data-field="marca"></tr>
        <tr><th data-field="modelo"></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-index="0">
            <td>Ford</td>
            <td>Modelo B</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr data-index="1">
            <td>Ford</td>
            <td>Kuga</td>           
        </tr>       
        <tr data-index="2">
            <td>FERRARI</td>
            <td>208</td>            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Con *JQuery* estoy intentando algo como esto, pero me "pinta" todas las celdas de color rojo, solo quiero que me pinte la última fila (la que contiene el string FERRARI)

```
$('table:contains("FERRARI"):last').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Gracias,

Comment: En la instrucción, estás diciendo que pinte la tabla... debes ser específico

Answer (score 0):

Como mencione anteriormente, estás fallando la instruccion JQuery, al darle el color a la tabla. Lo que realmente debes hacer, es esto:

```js
$("#tabla-marcas tr:contains('FERRARI')").css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla-marcas">
    <thead>
        <tr><th data-field="marca"></tr>
        <tr><th data-field="modelo"></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-index="0">
            <td>Ford</td>
            <td>Modelo B</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr data-index="1">
            <td>Ford</td>
            <td>Kuga</td>           
        </tr>       
        <tr data-index="2">
            <td>FERRARI</td>
            <td>208</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr data-index="3">
            <td>FERRARI</td>
            <td>DIABLO</td>            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias, tengo un botón que ejecuta la construcción de la tabla y al acabar deseo que busque "ferrari" y lo printe, para ello lo pongo en el botón de esta forma pero no me funciona

Comment: $('#tabla-marcas td:contains("FERRARI")').css('background-color','red');

Comment: Disculpa hice copy/paste erroneo mi id es "tabla-marcas"

Comment: Gracias ya lo correjí pero lo tengo dentro de un botón de esta forma y no me funciona. Primero cargo la tabla dinámicamente (eso funciona) y luego intento buscar el item para colorearlo

Comment: $("#btnCalculate").click(function(e){


            $('#tabla-marcas').bootstrapTable('refresh', {
                url: uri
            });

            $("#tabla-marcas td:contains('FERRARI')").css("background-color", "red");
            

        });

Comment: Algo como esto ?? http://jsfiddle.net/7dLq4okf/

Comment: @ilernet2 sigues por ahi ?